# What is the proper way to return from an exception in Scala?

Tags: scala

In a non-functional language, I might do something like:

```
try {
  // some stuff
} catch Exception ex {
  return false;
}

// Do more stuff

return true;
```

In Scala, however, this pattern is clearly not correct. If my scala code looks like this:

```
try {
  // do some stuff
}
catch {
  case e: Exception => // I want to get out of here and return false
  )
}

// do more stuff

true
```

How do I properly do that? I don't want to use the "return" statement, of course, but I also don't want to drop through and "do more stuff" and eventually return true.

Comment: I consider this as a bad pattern. I would add the "do more stuff" within the `try`, the `catch` being the last piece of code.

Comment: If I do that, I can then have any of a number of exceptions thrown within the try block and would have a very hard time differentiating between them. That would be worse.

Comment: See usages in docs for http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.Try, similarly http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Option, then scalaz solutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to represent a computation that can either succeed or signal that an error has occurred. That's the perfect use case for the `Try` monad.

```
import scala.util.{ Try, Success, Failure }

def myMethod: Try[Something] = Try {
  // do stuff
  // do more stuff
  // if any exception occurs here, it gets wrapped into a Failure(e)
}
```

So you're returning a `Try` instead of a `Bool`, which is infinitely more clear and idiomatic.

Usage example:

```
myMethod match {
  case Success(x) => println(s"computation succeded with result $x")
  case Failure(e) => println(s"computation failed with exception $e.getMessage")  
}
```

If you don't even care about the exception, but you just want to return a value in case of success, you can even convert the `Try` to an `Option`.

```
def myMethod: Option[Something] = Try {
  // do stuff
  // do more stuff
  // return something
  // if any exception occurs here, it gets wrapped into a Failure(e)
}.toOption

myMethod match {
  case Some(x) => println(s"computation succeded with result $x")
  case None => println("computation failed")  
}
```

---

To respond to the question in the comments, you can do

```
Try {
  // do stuff
} match {
   case Failure(_) => false
   case Success(_) =>
     // do more stuff
     // true
}
```

although I would suggest to return something more meaningful than a `Boolean`, whenever it makes sense.

Of course this can be nested

```
Try {
  // do stuff
} match {
   case Failure(_) => false
   case Success(_) =>
     // do more stuff
     Try {
       // something that can throw
     } match {
       case Failure(_) => false
       case Success(_) =>
         // do more stuff
         true
     }
}
```

but you should consider putting the `Try` chunks into separate functions (returning a `Try`).

Ultimately, we can take advantage of the fact that `Try` is a monad, and do something like this

```
Try { /* java code */ }.flatMap { _ =>
  // do more stuff
  Try { /* java code */ }.flatMap { _ =>
    // do more stuff
    Try { /* java code */ }
  }
} match {
  case Failure(_) => false // in case any of the Try blocks has thrown an Exception 
  case Success(_) => true // everything went smooth
}
```

Comment: Sure, but that's not my question - how do I return in the middle of a function when a failure occurs? I want to continue to do more work in the function if all is okay, but return if there's a failure in the middle.

Comment: Just wrap the code that it can fail in a `Try` and check it's result. See my update.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. That's what my code does now. Your example presumes that the try block is last in the function. It is not. There is more to do if the try block does not fail. What I need to know is what to do if the try block fails. There are multiple places in the function where I need to call into Java code that can throw an exception. I need to trap that exception, do something, and then return false.

Comment: In other words, my function does, in plain English: call a Java object's method. If it throws an exception, trap it, log it, return false. If no exception is thrown, call another method. If _it_ throws an exception, trap it, log it, return false. If no exception is thrown, repeat this for six or seven method calls. If you reach the end, return true.

Comment: You do more work in the `Success` case (i.e. the Try-wrapped code hasn't failed), see my updated example

Comment: See my brief example, the monadic goodness is that you do your success work in the map and your failure work in the recover (assuming you're returning some value like false, etc). Sorry I'm short of words. Easy to google it, I hope.

Comment: And I can nest more Try{} blocks in that success case? If so, gotcha!

Comment: No, no nested blocks!

Comment: If no nested blocks, then we're back to square one. I need to make multiple calls to different methods on a Java object, and each call can throw. I need to do them one at a time and get out if any fail. But I can't group them all in one big try, as I wouldn't know which one threw.

Comment: You can nest blocks, but you can take advantage of monad composition, which is way nicer. I'll post an example.

Comment: Okay, I get it. That makes sense, including putting the chunks into separate functions. I can then assign the result for further work, letting the Try block handle failure.

Comment: See the dividend example in the scaladoc for Try.

Comment: @ChristopherAmbler yep, and if you use monad composition, you will end up with a single `Try`, which will be a `Failure` in case any of the previous `Try` has failed, or `Success` otherwise. See my last example.

Comment: Thanks to both of you - that makes a lot of sense and suggests a good way to refactor this function to do it this way. That both solves the problem as well as teaches me a good pattern. Functional is fun ;)

Comment: You're welcome, and don't forget to check the syntactic sugar provided by for-comprehensions, which can make monad composition even cleaner.

Comment: As a note, `Try` is not a monad (even in the scala sense) because it doesn't respect the [left unit law](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.inf.ed.ac.uk%2Fwadler%2Fpapers%2Fmarktoberdorf%2Fbaastad.pdf&ei=yIcUVMCREKO6ygOk7ICIBA&usg=AFQjCNF195Aa51CrLJLed2BPDUhXTQ083w&sig2=SB2axjjtKqJ_Yv6sfRW1Nw)(page 11).

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> def f() = try { ??? ; 1 } catch { case _: Throwable => 2 }
f: ()Int

scala> f()
res2: Int = 2

scala> import util._
import util._

scala> def g() = Try { ??? ; 1 } recover { case _ => 2 } get
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
g: ()Int

scala> g()
res3: Int = 2
```

HTH. Small functions helps.

Another hint:

```
scala> def j() = Try (1) map (_ + 42) recover { case _ => 2 } get
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
j: ()Int

scala> j()
res4: Int = 43
```

Answer (score 1):

`try-catch` expression is not good for functional programming.

Anyway, an easy solution that still uses `try-catch`:

```
val result = try {
  // do some stuff
  Some(/* The final expression */)
}
catch {
  case e: Exception => // Do something or nothing
                       None
}

result match {
  case Some(r) => // Do something with r
                  true
  case None => false
}
```

You can use `scala.util.Try` for cleaner and more functional-styled code.
Refer to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38689/code-with-many-early-returns-exits-into-the-functional-style

I faced a similar problem like you, but the answer in the *Stackexchange CodeReview* helped me a lot.

Comment: I'm calling into Java code that throws an exception. I have no choice. My question isn't how to do this without exceptions, my question is how to return in mid-function. Your example presumes the function is done. My question is explicit that if there's no exception, there's more work to be done. How do I return if an exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Successful or erroneous cases can be represented by several Scala type.

If you consider the error in the meaning of "something is missing" (e.g. file not found), you can use `Option[T]` (e.g. `Option[File]`), with case values `None` or `Some(T)`. Then `orElse`, `getOrElse` or `fold` and `map`/`flatMap` functions can be used to dispatch cased.

You can also use `Either[E, T]`, with (by convention), in `Left(E)` case the error value (e.g. a `String` as error message), and in `Right(T)` successful `T` value.

Monads `Try[T]` or `Future[T]` can be used in the same way.

In the field of I/O, the very nice scala-arm lib provide type `ManagedResource[T]` that wrap either successful (`T`) or erroneous (`List[Throwable]]`) result of computation based on resources.

Valudation types in Scalaz are also useful for such cases.

Answer (score -1):

'util.Try{ do some stuff }.isSuccess'